# visual studio で InteliSense が制限されてしまいます

Tags: visual-studio

visual studioでPython言語環境を使用し始めたのですが、PythonでInteliSenseが制限されてしまいます。

一応、設定(詳細)を見たのですが、関係性がある項目が見つかりません。

ウインドウメニューの編集→InteliSenseを表示すると、キーボードショートカットが無効になっています。

InteliSenseは使えなくはないのですが、制限が気になるので、ご教示をお願いします。

私の環境が良くないので、携帯からの投稿になり、画像は上げられません。

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 何をもって制限されていると考えたのか、発生している現象を記述してみてください。例えばIntelliSenseが機能して表示されている何処かの資料や記事を示して、自分の環境ではこの時にこう表示されるはずのものが、何も表示されない/候補等が限られて表示される/全然別のものが表示される等の詳細です。

Answer (score 1):

それはVisualStudioの言語毎のサポート機能の差によるのかもしれませんね。

---

「現在のプロジェクトを分析しています。InteliSenseは制限されます。」と表示される件は、単なる一時的な状態表示では無いですか？

つまり「分析しています」なので分析している間だけ「InteliSenseは制限されます」だと思われます。
例えばこんな機能の説明があります。
[コードの色分け表示](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/python/editing-python-code-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#code-coloring)

> コードの色分け表示では、コード分析の情報を使用して、変数、ステートメント、その他のコード部分を色分けして示します。
>
> ヒント
> コードの色分け表示を無効にするには、 [ツール] > [オプション] > [テキスト エディター] > [Python] > [詳細設定] に移動し、 [その他のオプション] > Color names based on type をオフにします。 「Options - Miscellaneous Options」(オプション ∸ その他のオプション) を参照してください。

上記のような色分け表示とか、その解説ページのIntelliSenseでサポートしている機能そのものを実現するためにソースコード分析を行っていて、その分析が完了するまではIntelliSenseを完全な形で動作させることは出来ない、というだけでしょう。

---

「ウインドウメニューの（編集）から、InteliSenseの項目を表示すると、ショートカットのひと項目が選択できない。」に関して

選択できない項目とはこれでしょうか。
「IntelliSense の自動補完とタブのみの補完を切り替える(T) Ctrl+Alt+Space」

以下のようにC#(とVBも?)では有効で、C++では無効(メニューに項目はあるがグレーアウトで選択できない)なようです。
おそらくPythonもC++と同様にそういうモードは無い状態だと思われます。

[Visual Basic コード ファイルの IntelliSense](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/visual-basic-specific-intellisense?view=vs-2019)

> 自動補完

[[オプション]、[テキスト エディター]、[C#]、[IntelliSense]](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/reference/options-text-editor-csharp-intellisense?view=vs-2019)

> 名前の提案を表示
> 最近選択したメンバーのオブジェクト名の自動補完を実行します。

[VisualStudioのIntelliSenseが、Enterで決定できなくなった話（C#）](https://qiita.com/ShTair/items/18c7ece376794dcfa0c2)

> IntelliSenseには、2つのモードがあるらしい。
> 完了モード（標準の完了モード）と、提案モード（提案される完了モード）というようです。
>
> [CTRL] + [スペース]でIntelliSenseを出すことができるじゃないですか。多分この時に、間違えて[CTRL] + [ALT] + [スペース]を入力しちゃったんだろうなぁ…IntelliSenseにモードがあるとか、初めて知ったよ…

[VSCommunity2019のIntellisenceを提案モードに変更したいが、出来ない](https://teratail.com/questions/304419)

> また、Ctrl+Alt+Spaceは反応しませんでしたし、「メニューの『編集』→『IntelliSense』→『○○モードの切り替え』を押す」の選択肢も同様に色が薄くなり使用不可状態になっていました。
>
> 回答
> C++ にはモードの切り替えが無いようです。

Comment: 遅れてすみません。
記述されているものなどが分からないので、記述できないのですが、ウインドウバー（下）に読み込みの出力メッセージが出るんです。読んでいると、そこに「InteliSenseが制限されています」のように出力されるのですね。
ウインドウメニューの（編集）から、InteliSenseの項目を表示すると、ショートカットのひと項目が選択できない。そのような感じなのです。
一応、InteliSenseは動作するのですが、何とも気持ちが悪いので質問させて頂いた次第です。
私も、どう制限されているのか分からないのです。

Comment: ちなみに`「InteliSenseが制限されています」のように`というのは表示されている文言と同一ですか？ 質問者さんが要約したものだと検索とかしても見つからないかもしれないのでメッセージは表示されたままを記述してください。

Comment: 度々、ありがとうございます。
正確には「現在のプロジェクトを分析しています。InteliSenseは制限されます。」です。
制限をされているのは、何なのでしょう？